# What is the best way to store, a PHP array with objects in it, into a DB like SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite

Here is an extract of what I am trying to store in a SQLite DB:

```
array(10) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "cloudFiles"
  ["endpoints"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (4) {
      ["region"]=>
      string(3) "ORD"
```

What is the best way to store this in SQLite so that I can easily reconvert it to its original form?

Also in my SQLite DB I chose text for the format; is this good or is there another format that can let me store more information?

Comment: Normalize your database so you don't need to store nested data like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize it using [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). Then upon retrieval use [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: This will not work for PHP versions that can use closures when the object in context is using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `serialize` function to store PHP objects and convert them back with `unserialize`